# How to install Einstein module in Salesforce Commerce Cloud?

Tags: einstein, commerce-cloud

Does anyone how to install and upload Einstein module on the Salesforce commerce cloud?

Till now, i went through trailblazers some documentation but I could not any relevant information on that topic.

**Update:**
I went through the following guide.
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/cc-einstein-plan-and-implement/cc-einstein-deploy-site#deploy-einstein

It says the following line
***Einstein Deployment also feeds the data into the Configurator tool,***

I still could not find the Configurator tool.
Although, I found the **Einstein Status Dashboard** under **Administration** -> **Operations** but that was under Salesforce cloud section not where Einstein has configured. Also, it shows feed data is in Good quality but Einstein column shows not configured (second column).

Comment: Hope you have checked with [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/deploy-commerce-cloud-einstein) too?

Comment: Thanks @ShivankurNaikwade I had already checked the but where to configure and which module to upload that is still i m wondering - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/cc-einstein-plan-and-implement/cc-einstein-deploy-site#deploy-einstein

Comment: You can find the Einstein configurator under https://configurator.cquotient.com/